# Timestamp doesn't constrain data in SQL query when defining set timestamp parameters to restrict results

Tags: sql, websphere

I can't currently constrain the result set to the time period that I'm interested in using the current code below. I'm using timeplaced which is in a timestamp format of 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and I want to restrict it to between

I've tried to change the formatting of the WHERE clause to 'date(timeplaced)' and 'timestamp(timeplaced)' however this returns the same results.

```
  select * from mqtvworderitems
  where WCID like '340-84010339-TGB07623'
  AND timeplaced BETWEEN '2019-09-29 00:00:00' AND '2019-10-14 23:59:59'
```

The expected results are results constrained within the time constraints, however I get results that sit outside the constraints (e.g. 2019:09-12 12:26:09).

Comment: What data type is your `timeplaced` column

Comment: Please tag with database platform.

Comment: @dvo the data type is strictly 'smalldatetime'

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this error... Can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) that recreates the error? If not, I don't think the `BETWEEN` is the issue.

Comment: @DanHammond94 - There is no `smalldatetime` in Oracle.  Are you using a different database engine?  If so, which one (and update the tags accordingly).

Comment: @JustinCave apologies, I was mistaken, the database engine is Websphere, not Oracle.

Comment: WebSphere is an application server, not a database.  Based on the column type being `smalldatetime`, could it possibly be Microsoft SQL Server database that you are using?  I know that has a `smalldatetime` type, although others might have that type as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the date/timestamp format.  For example:

```
BETWEEN to_timestamp('2019-09-29 00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND to_timestamp('2019-10-14 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_TIMESTAMP.html#GUID-57E09334-E3CC-4CA2-809E-F0909458BCFA) for more.

Answer (score 0):

If it turns out you are using Microsoft SQL Server database, give this a try and see if the comparison operators work any better,

```
  select * from mqtvworderitems
  where WCID like '340-84010339-TGB07623'
  AND timeplaced >= '2019-09-29 00:00:00' AND timeplaced <= '2019-10-14 23:59:59'
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion but it provides me with the same result as I saw previously (data is unconstrained within the specified dates).